# PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell 7 throws ActiveDirectory errors

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We're in the process of upgrading PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell 7 and have some issues regarding the module 'ActiveDirectory'.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -SkipEditionCheck

$adGroup = New-Object Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup Identity -Property @{
    Description    = 'ROL group'
    CanonicalName  = 'contoso.com/Groups/test'
    SamAccountName = 'test'
    GroupCategory  = 'Security'
    GroupScope     = 'Universal'
}
```

This throws 2 errors:

> Could not load type 'System.Management.Automation.PSSnapIn' from assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=7.3.8.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> New-Object:

> The member "Description" was not found for the specified .NET object.

When we inspect this object with `$adGroup | Get-Member` it seems that the properties `Description` and `CanonicalName` are not available on this object.

In PowerShell 5.1 this code was working flawlessly. What is the best way for mocking an AD security group that works in both PowerShell versions?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error (tested with PS 7.3.8)

Comment: We're running this code on Windows Server 2016, which doesn't have the latest and greatest ActiveDirectory module. See also [this article](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2264395-error-affecting-powershell-7-on-server-2016-with-ad-need-to-update-ad-module?page=1#entry-8814401) .

Answer (score 0):

This might not work, I don't have an environment to test at this time of the day.

To address this issue and create a script that works in both PowerShell versions, you can utilize the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, which provides a more consistent way to interact with Active Directory across different PowerShell versions. Below is an example of how you can create a new AD group using this namespace:

```
# Required for compatibility between PowerShell 5.1 and 7
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

# Establish the context for the domain
$contextType = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$principalContext = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $contextType

# Create a new group principal
$groupPrincipal = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal -ArgumentList $principalContext

# Set the properties for the group
$groupPrincipal.Description = 'ROL group'
$groupPrincipal.Name = 'test'
$groupPrincipal.SamAccountName = 'test'
$groupPrincipal.Save()

# Get the newly created group
$newGroup = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($principalContext, 'test')

# Output the group details
$newGroup | Format-List *
```

Using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace helps to create a consistent approach for managing Active Directory across different versions of PowerShell. Make sure you have the necessary permissions to create AD objects before running the script.

This approach SHOULD work seamlessly in both PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.

Comment: Thank you but it throws the error `Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied. "`. Probably because I don't have write permissions in AD.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you had rights. Well that's another issue lol.